# Java code for Distance formula from input (1,2)(2,3)

Tags: java

I am trying to take input coordinates from console which is of the form `(x1,y1)`.

How do I select only the numbers(and avoid brackets) from the input?
I know i'll have to use regular expression and parse the input, but don't know how to do that for this code

```
import java.io.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] input1 = br.readLine().split(",");
        String[] input2 = br.readLine().split(",");
        double x1 = Double.valueOf(input1[0]);
        double y1 = Double.valueOf(input1[1]);


        double x2 = Double.valueOf(input2[0]);
        double y2 = Double.valueOf(input2[1]);

        double result = Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the data have to be in the (x, y) format?

Comment: Yes, the input is in multiple pairs and is in the format (x,y)

Comment: you dont have to use regular expression. you can simply strip the bracket.

Comment: Just a note, you can use `Math.hypot(double, double)` for calculating the distance between two points. In your case, `Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`. See [Math.hypot(double, double) for details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use regular expressions to take numbers from text.
Something like this:

```
String input = br.readLine();
// Compile you pattern with two groups to capture each num
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\)");
// Match your input
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
// If your input matches to pattern you want, then you take numbers
if (matcher.find()) {
    double x = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1);
    double y = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(3);
    //... Other code you need
}
```

Finally, I would recommend you to read more about regular expressions, for example here: 
[Regular Expressions TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: I will definitely go through the example given on TutorialsPoint...Thank you!